# Error when referencing a class within its __init__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tensorflow, machine-translation

I am putting the  ([NMT Tensorflow code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb#scrollTo=hpObfY22IddU)) inside a main class. The code base has two classes - 'Encoder' and 'Decoder'. They are referenced in their respective 'init' methods. However it raises an error - 'Undefined named Encoder'.

```
class TranslationModel(ModelBase):



    pathToZip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('spa-eng.zip', origin='http://download.tensorflow.org/data/spa-eng.zip', extract=True)

    pathToFile = os.path.dirname(pathToZip)+"/spa-eng/spa.txt"


    def __init__(self,
                 batchSize = 64,
                 bufferSize = None,
                 numberOfBatches = None,
                 units = 1024,
                 vocabInputSize = None,
                 vocabTargetSize = None,
                 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
                 dataSetPath = None,
                 inputTensor = None,
                 targetTensor = None,
                 inputLanguage = None,
                 targetLanguage = None,
                 maxLengthInput = None,
                 maxLengthTarget = None,
                 embeddingDimension  = 256, *arg, **kwargs):
        self.batchSize          = 64
        self.bufferSize         = None
        self.numberOfBatches    = None
        self.units              = units
        self.vocabInputSize     = None
        self.vocabTargetSize    = None
        self.optimizer          = optimizer
        self.dataSetPath        = dataSetPath
        self.targetTensor       = targetTensor
        self.inputTensor        = inputTensor
        self.inputLanguage      = inputLanguage
        self.targetLanguage     = targetLanguage
        self.maxLengthInput     = maxLengthInput
        self.maxLengthTarget    = maxLengthTarget
        self.embeddingDimension = embeddingDimension
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwargs)

        #OTHER FUNCTIONS HERE

    class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
        def __init__(self, vocabSize, embeddingDimension, encoderUnits, batchSize):
            super(Encoder, self).__init__() # Raises error - 'Undefined named Encoder'
        #Other code here



    class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
        def __init__(self, vocabSize, embeddingDimension, dec_units, batchSize):
            super('Decoder', self).__init__() # Raises error - 'Undefined named Decoder'
        ## Other code
```

Comment: I made a toy example and cannot reproduce: `class F: def __init__(self): self.foo = 'foo'; class G(F): def __init__(self): super(G,self).__init__() self.bar = 'bar'; g = G()` ... Python 3.6.

Comment: @wwii I have edited the post with more code. 'Translation Model' is my class, inside which there are 'Encoder' and 'Decoder' classes.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. There are errors that make it difficult to understand what the actual code looks like.

Comment: @BryanOakley my bad, edited nw.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you have a class inside of another and you want to identify it, you should do it this way : OutterClass.InnerClass

it won't work if you just use : InnerClass

for your case it's TranslationModel.Encoder